# String(33, 0) in VB 6.0 and equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb6

What is the meaning of `UserName = String(33, 0)` in VB 6.0 and what will be the equivalent in C#.

Please help I'm getting error while converting VB 6.0 code into C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vb. What does this `String()` do exactly?

Comment: UserName = String(33, 0) generates a compiler error...

Comment: Did you test it, what does it do?

Comment: In the VB6 code, what happens to UserName next? Do you by any chance pass it to the Win32 function named `GetUserName`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` in VB6 is a function that returns a string containing a repeating character string of the length specified.

```
String(number,character)
```

example:

```
strTest = String(5, "a")
' strTest = "aaaaa"

strTest = String(5, 97)
' strTest = "aaaaa" (97 is the ASCII code for "a")
```

In this case, `String(33,0)` will return a string containing 33 null characters.

The equivalent in C# would be

```
UserName = new String('\0', 33);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... now i got the concept.

Comment: Actually it returns a Variant of subtype String.  String$() is the preferred version of this function.

Answer (score 5):

In VB6, that function creates a string that contains 33 characters, all of whom have zero ordinal value.

Typically you do that because you are about to pass the string to some native function which fills out the buffer. In C# the closest equivalent to that would be to create a `StringBuilder` instance which you would then pass to the native code in a p/invoke function call.

I think that a direct translation of that single line of code is not particularly useful. That code exists in context and I strongly suspect that the context is important.

So, whilst you could create a new C# `string` with 33 null characters, what would be the point of that? Since the .net string is immutable, you cannot do very much of interest with it. In your VB6 code you will surely be mutating that object, and so `StringBuilder` is, in my view, the most likely tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for:

```
UserName = new String((Char)0, 33);
```

Reference [this](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions) for what the VB6 method did.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an function that perform this action, or o can do a extenssion of the class `String`.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strGen("01",3));
    }
    //param s is the string that you can generete and the n param is the how many times.
    private static string strGen(String s, int n){
        string r = string.Empty;
        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
            r += string.Copy(s);
        return r;
    }
}
```